# Translating js code from Jade to EJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

I have the following code in Jade, and I am trying to translate it to EJS, but quite unfamiliar with Jade (Or ejs for that matter).
I've started but not quite sure if I am doing it correctly.
Also, why can't I just use normal javascript in ejs rather than using the syntax which is quite confusing ?
thank you!

Original code in Jade:

```
body
    h1= collection
    #objects
        table(border=1)
          if objects.length > 0
              - each val, key in objects[0]
                  th= key 
          - each obj in objects
            tr.obj
              - each val, key in obj
                td.key= val
```

translation I've started:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <h1>collection</h1>

        <table style="border:1px">
        <% if (objects.length > 0) { %>

        </table>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The translation of your Jade code would be:

```
<body>
    <h1>collection</h1>
    <div id="objects">
    <table border="1">
    <% if (objects.length > 0) { 
         for(i=0;i<objects[0].length;i++){
             %>
                <th><%=objects[0][i]%></th>
             <%
          }
        for(i=0;i<objects.length;i++){
            var obj=objects[i];
              %>
              <tr>
              <%for(j=0;j<obj.length;j++){
                %>
                  <td><%=obj[j]%></td>
                <%
               }%>
              </tr>
              <%
          }

     } %>
    </table>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: As you see EJS is much more verbose, that's why most of the nodejs community prefers jade. You can easily learn and get used to Jade syntax.